# copying SD card of Raspberry-pi to another SD card

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspberry-pi but I'm still beginner
I found a project using camera module for face-detection
Can I copy the image of the SD card of this project to new SD card and put it to my Raspberry, Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions from the link below.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-super-easy-r-1261113524

Comment: thank you very much JOSEMR
that is exactly what I want .